# InSpec: "Cannot load <profile> since it is not listed as a dependency" when dependency is defined

Tags: inspec

In InSpec 1.9.0 I defined the following profile with dependency, including all controls from the dependent profile.

However, when executing I get the error indicating the profile "*is not listed as dependency*"

What am I missing?

---

- `inspec.yml`:

  ```
  name: my-profile
  version: 0.0.1
  supports:
    - os-family: unix
  depends:
    - name: ssh-baseline
      url: https://github.com/dev-sec/ssh-baseline/archive/master.zip
  ```
- `controls/include_ssh_baseline.rb`:

  ```
  include_controls 'ssh-baseline'
  ```
- Command:

  ```
  inspec exec my-profile -t ssh://user@host.domain
  ```
- The result of executing the profile:

  > Cannot load ssh-baseline since it is not listed as a dependency
  >   of my-profile.
  >
  > Dependencies available from this context are:

  (two empty lines)

I don't see a syntax error. It's almost copy-paste example from [InSpec Profiles](http://inspec.io/docs/reference/profiles/) page.

The following dependency definition (`git` instead of `url`) also caused the same error message as above:

```
depends:
  - name: ssh-baseline
    git: https://github.com/dev-sec/ssh-baseline.git
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inspec.lock` file is created on the first profile execution and contains a reference to the dependencies. If you build your profile incrementally you might end up with an `inspec.yml` file containing no dependencies (from the first run):

```
---
lockfile_version: 1
depends: []
```

You need to delete the file if you want changes to the `inspec.yml` to be reflected or run the following inside the profile directory:

```
inspec vendor --overwrite
```

---

See [Vendoring dependencies](https://github.com/chef/inspec/blob/master/docs/profiles.md#vendoring-dependencies) (it doesn't mention `--overwrite`, but it immediately throws an error if it's not present):

> When you execute a local profile, the `inspec.yml` file will be read in order to source any profile dependencies. It will then cache the dependencies locally and generate an `inspec.lock` file. If you add or update dependencies in `inspec.yml`, please refresh the lock file by either:
>
> - running `inspec vendor` inside the profile directory; or
> - deleting `inspec.lock` before running inspec exec

Answer (score 1):

I just created it a profile based on your post and it works without any issues. I used inspec 1.9.0. Just to be sure, can you try `inspec exec ./my-profile -t ssh://user@host.domain`?

Comment: Thank you, it helped. I wasn't aware of `inspec.lock` caching dependencies (or rather lack of dependencies) if I first execute the profile without them. [Answered myself](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41772686/2947502).